# Android List View, In Alert Dialog Showing Same Item

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I have created an Alert Dialog which shows a list view of addresses that the user has searched. However when the alert dialog is shown with the list view items, I get same item repeated, so if I got 6 addresses i'll get item 3 in the address collection repeating 6 times.

I have debugged, and the address collection does show unique items, however something is going wrong in between creating the dialog, and setting the adapter for the listview. I think it is something to do with the convertView in the AddressRowAdapter class, but I am not too sure.

Here is the code.

This is the SearchLocation class, the resource_address_listview contains a ListView widget, which is in a RelativeLayout

```
//set our adapter
AddressRowAdapter dataAdapter = new AddressRowAdapter(getActivity(), addressList);

//Create Address Selection Dialog
AlertDialog.Builder addressSelectionDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
//Get the layout file
LayoutInflater alertDialogInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
//Get our custom view
View getAlertDialogView = alertDialogInflater.inflate(R.layout.resource_address_listview,null);

//Set our custom view
addressSelectionDialog.setView(getAlertDialogView);

//Set up, confirmation buttons and events for dialog
addressSelectionDialog.setPositiveButton("Select", new AlertDialogPositiveButtonClick());
addressSelectionDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new AlertDialogCancelButtonClick());

//Set up our adapter

//Get our list view
listViewAddressList = (ListView)getAlertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.listViewAddressList);
listViewAddressList.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

//listViewAddressList.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);//Single choice mode, radio buttons
listViewAddressList.setOnItemClickListener(new AddressListViewOnItemClick());//Set our item click listener.

//Create and show dialog
createDialog = addressSelectionDialog.create();
createDialog.show();
```

Here is the code for the AddressRowAdapter,  I believe something here is wrong but I can't see anything wrong with the code.

public class AddressRowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
//Initialize private variables.
private Context context;
private List<Address> addresses;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public AddressRowAdapter(Context context, List<Address> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);

    this.context = context;
    this.addresses = objects;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    //Setup location variables.
    String _county = "";
    String _subCounty = "";
    String _country = "";
    String _countryCode = "";
    String _postcode = "";
    String _addressLine="";
    String _seperator = " ";
    String _comma = ",";


    //If no view is provided, get the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, parent, false);
    }

    //Find all controls in view.
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

    //loop through all the addresses.
    for (int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++)
    {
        //Get address.
        Address thisAddress = addresses.get(i);

        //if it has no long/lat coordinates we do not need it.
        if (!thisAddress.hasLatitude() && !thisAddress.hasLongitude())
            break;

        if (thisAddress.getAddressLine(0) != null)
            _addressLine = thisAddress.getAddressLine(0) + _seperator;

        if (thisAddress.getAdminArea() != null)
            _county=thisAddress.getAdminArea() + _comma;

        if(thisAddress.getSubAdminArea() != null)
            _subCounty=thisAddress.getSubAdminArea() + _seperator;

        if (thisAddress.getPostalCode() != null)
            _postcode = thisAddress.getPostalCode() + _seperator;

        if (thisAddress.getCountryCode() != null)
            _countryCode=thisAddress.getCountryCode() + _comma;

        if (thisAddress.getCountryName() != null)
            _country = thisAddress.getCountryName();


        textView.setText(_addressLine + _county + _subCounty + _postcode + _countryCode + _country);

    }
    return convertView;
}


@Nullable
@Override
public Address getItem(int position) {
    return addresses.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return addresses.size();
}
```

}

I have debugged this countless times, and the address collection always shows unique items, and I don't seem to be overwriting/replacing them, so I am completely lost to what is going on.

Any help would be appreciated

Kind regards

Comment: add AddressRowAdapter full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using for loop in Adapter? There is no need of for loop. You can directly use

```
Address thisAddress = addresses.get(position);
```

Adapter will create the view for the number of count returned by **getCount()** method. So, if you are returning correct count it will automatically create view for all addresses.

```
public int getCount(){
     return addresses.size();
}
```

Comment: Thank You, Yes I did not need the loop and that seems to have resolved the issue.